# JSON/JavaScript Functionality/Implementation

Tags: javascript, html

This code should: locate courses from the object that match the day of the button selected (for instance,Monday), then; sort that list based on the starting time. Due to the nature of the information in the Object, I converted them to their military equivalent for comparison purposes. Once that is done, it should finally display the list of sorted courses with the information specified in the statement.

When I select a button however, nothing occurs. Nothing is displayed, nor do I get any errors in my code when I compile it.

```
var courses = [
  {
    "dept": "CSC",
    "id": "3102",
    "instructor": "Kooima",
    "Location": "230 Turead",
    "Start_Time": "1130",
    "End_Time": "1230",
    "Attendance": "Tuesday",
    "Full_Name": "Advanced Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis"
  },
  {
    "dept": "CSC",
    "id": "1200",
    "instructor": "Duncan",
    "Location": "420 PFT",
    "Start_Time": "1030",
    "End_Time": "1130",
    "Attendance": "Monday",
    "Full_Name": "Ethics in Computer Science"
  },
  {
    "dept": "CSC",
    "id": "4330",
    "instructor": "Mahmoud",
    "Location": "150 Coates",
    "Start_Time": "12:30",
    "End_Time": "1:30",
    "Attendance": "Thursday",
    "Full_Name": "Software Systems Development"
  },
  {
    "dept": "MATH",
    "id": "1550",
    "instructor": "Tom",
    "Location": "012 Lockett",
    "Start_Time": "12:30",
    "End_Time": "1:30",
    "Attendance": "Wednesday",
    "Full_Name": "Calculus"
  },
  {
    "dept": "ENGL",
    "id": "2000",
    "instructor": "McKinnon",
    "Location": "012 Allen Hall",
    "Start_Time": "9:30",
    "End_Time": "10:30",
    "Attendance": "Friday",
    "Full_Name": "English Composition"
  },
  {
    "dept": "THTR",
    "id": "1020",
    "instructor": "King",
    "Location": "619 MDMA",
    "Start_Time": "8:30",
    "End_Time": "9:30",
    "Attendance": "Wednesday",
    "Full_Name": "Introduction to Theatre"
  }

];

var courseDayList = new Array();

function converTime(time) {
  var numericTime = 0;
  if (time == "8:30") numericTime = 830;
  if (time == "9:30") numericTime = 930;
  if (time == "10:30") numericTime = 1030;
  if (time == "11:30") numericTime = 1130;
  if (time == "12:30") numericTime = 1230;
  return numericTime;
}

function showCourseFromDay(day) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i<courses.length; i++) {
    var course = courses[i];
    console.log(course);
    if (course.Attendance == day) {
      courseDayList.push(course);
    }
  }
  courseDayList.bubbleSort = new function () {
    var swapped;
    do {
      swapped = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < courseDayList.length - 1; i++) {
        var time1 = convertTime(courseDayList[i].Start_Time);
        var time2 = convertTime(courseDayList[i + 1].Start_Time);
        if (time1 > time2) {
          var temp = courseDayList[i];
          courseDayList[i] = courseDayList[i + 1];
          courseDayList[i + 1] = temp;
          swapped = true;
        }
      }
    } while (swapped);
  }
  courseDayList.bubbleSort();
  courseDayList.printCourses = new function () {
    var counter = 0;
    while (counter == courseDayList.length) {
      var courseName = document.getElementById("cName");
      var courseTime = document.getElementById("cTime");
      var courseLocation = document.getElementById("cLocation");
      courseName.innerHTML = courseDayList[counter].dept + " " + courseDayList[counter].id + "- " + courseDayList[counter].Full_Name + "<br />";
      courseTime.innerHTML = courseDayList[counter].Start_Time + "-" + courseDayList[counter].End_Time + "<br />";
      courseLocation.innerHTML = courseDayList[counter].Location;
      counter++;
    }
  }
  courseDayList.printCourses();
}


<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>Today's Schedule</h4>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="showCourseFromDay('Monday')">Monday</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="showCourseFromDay('Tuesday')">Tuesday</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="showCourseFromDay('Wednesday')">Wednesday</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="showCourseFromDay('Thursday')">Thursday</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="showCourseFromDay('Friday')">Friday</button>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div style="border-color:rebeccapurple"></div>
        <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="course in schedule">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <h4 id="cName"></h4>
                <p id="cTime"></p>
                <p id="cLocation"></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is there an error? If so, what is the error message? Is the code not behaving as you expect? If so, what happens? What do you expect should happen?

Comment: Sorry for not including that information. Idealistically, the code should: locate courses from the JSON object that match the day of the button selected (for instance,Monday), then; sort that list based on the starting time. Due to the nature of the information in JSON Object, I converted them to their military equivalent for comparison purposes. Once that is done, it should finally display the list of sorted courses with the information specified in the statement. I've been trying to test it using buttons on a barebones HTML page set to run the function onclick, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Update this in your question please

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle

Comment: `Idealistically, the code should` ... `but it doesn't seem to work` - if you want help, describe what you observe instead of what should idealistically happen ... browser developer tools has a console to help - use it

Comment: Done and, sorta done.  Working out the details for it now

Comment: a) your `convertTime` function only returns a time if it needed converting otherwise it returns 0, but that doesn't matter because you never call `convertTime` function anyway, c) you never call `showCourseFromDay` either - so, all in all, you've code with flawed logic, that never gets called anyway

Comment: Do you have any solutions towards re-mediating these issues? Should I simply add an eventListener to the buttons, or am I approaching this issue wrong in its entirety? Thank you in advance

Comment: Please give your post a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1):

```
var courses = [
  {
    "dept": "CSC",
    "id": "3102",
    "instructor": "Kooima",
    "Location": "230 Turead",
    "Start_Time": "1130",
    "End_Time": "1230",
    "Attendance": "Tuesday",
    "Full_Name": "Advanced Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis"
  },
  {
    "dept": "CSC",
    "id": "1200",
    "instructor": "Duncan",
    "Location": "420 PFT",
    "Start_Time": "1030",
    "End_Time": "1130",
    "Attendance": "Monday",
    "Full_Name": "Ethics in Computer Science"
  },
  {
    "dept": "CSC",
    "id": "4330",
    "instructor": "Mahmoud",
    "Location": "150 Coates",
    "Start_Time": "12:30",
    "End_Time": "1:30",
    "Attendance": "Thursday",
    "Full_Name": "Software Systems Development"
  },
  {
    "dept": "MATH",
    "id": "1550",
    "instructor": "Tom",
    "Location": "012 Lockett",
    "Start_Time": "12:30",
    "End_Time": "1:30",
    "Attendance": "Wednesday",
    "Full_Name": "Calculus"
  },
  {
    "dept": "ENGL",
    "id": "2000",
    "instructor": "McKinnon",
    "Location": "012 Allen Hall",
    "Start_Time": "9:30",
    "End_Time": "10:30",
    "Attendance": "Friday",
    "Full_Name": "English Composition"
  },
  {
    "dept": "THTR",
    "id": "1020",
    "instructor": "King",
    "Location": "619 MDMA",
    "Start_Time": "8:30",
    "End_Time": "9:30",
    "Attendance": "Wednesday",
    "Full_Name": "Introduction to Theatre"
  }

];

var courseDayList = new [];

function convertTime(time) {
  var numericTime = 0;
  if (time == "8:30") numericTime = 830;
  if (time == "9:30") numericTime = 930;
  if (time == "10:30") numericTime = 1030;
  if (time == "11:30") numericTime = 1130;
  if (time == "12:30") numericTime = 1230;
  return numericTime;
}

function showCourseFromDay(day) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i<courses.length; i++) {
    var course = courses[i];
    console.log(course);
    if (course.Attendance == day) {
      courseDayList.push(course);
    }
  }
  courseDayList.bubbleSort =  function () {
    var swapped;
    do {
      swapped = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < courseDayList.length - 1; i++) {
        var time1 = convertTime(courseDayList[i].Start_Time);
        var time2 = convertTime(courseDayList[i + 1].Start_Time);
        if (time1 > time2) {
          var temp = courseDayList[i];
          courseDayList[i] = courseDayList[i + 1];
          courseDayList[i + 1] = temp;
          swapped = true;
        }
      }
    } while (swapped);
  }
  courseDayList.bubbleSort();
  courseDayList.printCourses = function () {
    var counter = 0;
    while (counter == courseDayList.length) {
      var courseName = document.getElementById("cName");
      var courseTime = document.getElementById("cTime");
      var courseLocation = document.getElementById("cLocation");
      courseName.innerHTML = courseDayList[counter].dept + " " + courseDayList[counter].id + "- " + courseDayList[counter].Full_Name + "<br />";
      courseTime.innerHTML = courseDayList[counter].Start_Time + "-" + courseDayList[counter].End_Time + "<br />";
      courseLocation.innerHTML = courseDayList[counter].Location;
      counter++;
    }
  }
  courseDayList.printCourses();
}
```

Test if this works. Some corrections:

1. Some functions were misspelled.
2. Syntax for creating a function is simply `function() {...` not `new function() {...`

Comment: Haven't been able to test it, I can't seem to find a way to invoke the function for testing purposes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Quick testing: paste it on to a script tag on your page, and delete any previous versions of the script to prevent name conflict (old version overriding new version). Additionally, ensure you have Angular.js (https://angularjs.org/ for more info) loaded, as you have `ng-repeat` in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Had a few issues...

1) The convertTime function was misspelt
2) Nested functions (printCourses and bubbleSort should have been moved out in global scope)
3) The list structure in HTML could only support a single output
4) The array was never being cleared out
5) The printCourses function would never run since the counter (always 0) was being tested against the size of the list (never 0)

Here's a fiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/jecfkoy7/

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4>Today's Schedule</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="showCourseFromDay('Monday')">Monday</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="showCourseFromDay('Tuesday')">Tuesday</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="showCourseFromDay('Wednesday')">Wednesday</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="showCourseFromDay('Thursday')">Thursday</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="showCourseFromDay('Friday')">Friday</button>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div style="border-color:rebeccapurple"></div>
    <ul id="list" class="list-group" ng-repeat="course in schedule">
      <!--<li class="list-group-item">
        <h4 id="cName"></h4>
        <p id="cTime"></p>
        <p id="cLocation"></p>
      </li>-->
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

var courses = [{
    "dept": "CSC",
    "id": "3102",
    "instructor": "Kooima",
    "Location": "230 Turead",
    "Start_Time": "1130",
    "End_Time": "1230",
    "Attendance": "Tuesday",
    "Full_Name": "Advanced Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis"
  }, {
    "dept": "CSC",
    "id": "1200",
    "instructor": "Duncan",
    "Location": "420 PFT",
    "Start_Time": "1030",
    "End_Time": "1130",
    "Attendance": "Monday",
    "Full_Name": "Ethics in Computer Science"
  }, {
    "dept": "CSC",
    "id": "4330",
    "instructor": "Mahmoud",
    "Location": "150 Coates",
    "Start_Time": "12:30",
    "End_Time": "1:30",
    "Attendance": "Thursday",
    "Full_Name": "Software Systems Development"
  }, {
    "dept": "MATH",
    "id": "1550",
    "instructor": "Tom",
    "Location": "012 Lockett",
    "Start_Time": "12:30",
    "End_Time": "1:30",
    "Attendance": "Wednesday",
    "Full_Name": "Calculus"
  }, {
    "dept": "ENGL",
    "id": "2000",
    "instructor": "McKinnon",
    "Location": "012 Allen Hall",
    "Start_Time": "9:30",
    "End_Time": "10:30",
    "Attendance": "Friday",
    "Full_Name": "English Composition"
  }, {
    "dept": "THTR",
    "id": "1020",
    "instructor": "King",
    "Location": "619 MDMA",
    "Start_Time": "8:30",
    "End_Time": "9:30",
    "Attendance": "Wednesday",
    "Full_Name": "Introduction to Theatre"
  }

];

var courseDayList = new Array();

convertTime = function(time) {
  var numericTime = 0;
  if (time == "8:30") numericTime = 830;
  if (time == "9:30") numericTime = 930;
  if (time == "10:30") numericTime = 1030;
  if (time == "11:30") numericTime = 1130;
  if (time == "12:30") numericTime = 1230;
  return numericTime;
}

bubbleSort = function() {
    var swapped;
    do {
      swapped = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < courseDayList.length - 1; i++) {
        var time1 = convertTime(courseDayList[i].Start_Time);
        var time2 = convertTime(courseDayList[i + 1].Start_Time);
        if (time1 > time2) {
          var temp = courseDayList[i];
          courseDayList[i] = courseDayList[i + 1];
          courseDayList[i + 1] = temp;
          swapped = true;
        }
      }
    } while (swapped);
  }

  printCourses = function() {
    var counter = 0;
    while (counter <= courseDayList.length - 1) {
      /*var courseName = document.getElementById("cName");
      var courseTime = document.getElementById("cTime");
      var courseLocation = document.getElementById("cLocation");*/
      var courseName = courseDayList[counter].dept + " " + courseDayList[counter].id + "- " + courseDayList[counter].Full_Name;
      var courseTime = courseDayList[counter].Start_Time + "-" + courseDayList[counter].End_Time;
      var courseLocation = courseDayList[counter].Location;

      var list = document.getElementById('list');
      var entry = document.createElement('li');
        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(courseName));
      entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(courseTime));
      entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(courseLocation));
        list.appendChild(entry);    

      counter++;
    }

  }

showCourseFromDay = function(day) {

    //Clear existing records
  var list = document.getElementById('list');
  while (list.firstChild) list.removeChild(list.firstChild);

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    var course = courses[i];
    console.log(course);
    if (course.Attendance == day) {
      courseDayList.push(course);
    }
  }

  bubbleSort();
  printCourses();
  courseDayList = new Array();
}
```

Comment: Glad to help, mark it as the answer if your issue was resolved, thanks.